# How can I save and get a image from my database

Tags: java, android, sql

I take a picture and save the path into my SQLite database but it only saves 0 kb file and when I try to open it with the gallery it is not opening

this is my main activity:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

Button btnTakePicture;
ImageView imageView;
String pathToFile;
Intent takePictureIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnTakePicture = findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicture);



    final EditText txtname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtname);

    Button mcbutton = (Button) findViewById((R.id.mcbutton));
    Button listbutton = (Button) findViewById((R.id.listbutton));


    final DataBase db = new DataBase(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        db.onCreate(db.getWritableDatabase());
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
    }

    btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    mcbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String fname = txtname.getText().toString();

            if (fname == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter something!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else if (pathToFile == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please take a picture!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {

                Model model = new Model(fname, pathToFile);


                long id = db.ekleModel(model);

                if (id > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Food Registration Perfect! ID = " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    txtname.setText("");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter a Food Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    listbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Random.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() throws IOException {
    takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createPhotoFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
}

private File createPhotoFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName + ".jpg");
    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    pathToFile = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

and this is my other activity where I get the problem,
everything is supposed to work but I don't know why bitmap decode returns null...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_random);

    final EditText txtMulti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMulti);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    DataBase db = new DataBase(getApplicationContext());

    List<Model> modellist = new ArrayList<Model>();
    modellist = db.gelModelListesi();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(Model _model: modellist){
          String icerik = "";
          icerik = "ID: "+_model.getId()+"Yemek Adı: "+_model.getFoodname()+ "\n\n";

          File imgFile = new File(_model.getImagePath());

        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getPath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }

          sb.append(icerik);
    }
    txtMulti.setText(sb);
}
```

Comment: Why you save photos in database instead you can save path of the photo in database then retrieve and show in imageview according to path.And use Glide or Picasso to show image in imageview.

Comment: You failed to put a `Uri` to the desired file in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` of your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`. As a result, nothing will be saved to that file. Instead, you are getting the `"data"` extra with the `Bitmap`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) and [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera/FileProvider) (from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android)).